# How to add custom submenu links in wp-admin menus?

Tags: wp-admin, admin-menu, add-submenu-page

Is it possible to add custom links as submenu on menu that already exist in wp-admin? Like for example, under appearance section like this:
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the custom link into the admin menu, you need to pick up a top-level menu item by its slug and register the function using the [admin_menu](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_menu) action hook.

Here is the list of Main Admin Menu slugs.

```
index.php => Dashboard
edit.php => Posts
upload.php => Media
link-manager.php => Links
edit.php?post_type=page => Pages
edit-comments.php => Comments
themes.php => Appearance
plugins.php => Plugins
users.php => Users
tools.php => Tools
options-general.php => Settings
```

List of all admin menus and submenus names, keys, and slugs. [Image Source](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/customizing-your-wordpress-admin--wp-24941)

[image]

If you want to use the external link then the code is:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_custom_link_into_appearnace_menu');
function add_custom_link_into_appearnace_menu() {
    global $submenu;
    $permalink = 'http://www.cusomtlink.com';
    $submenu['themes.php'][] = array( 'Custom Link', 'manage_options', $permalink );
}
```

If you want to render the custom link page using [WordPress Administrations Menus](https://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus) functions then the code is:

```
 add_action('admin_menu', 'add_custom_link_into_appearnace_menu');
 function add_custom_link_into_appearnace_menu() {
    add_theme_page('Custom Link Pgae Title', 'Custom Link Menu Title', 'manage_options', 'custom-link-unique-identifier', 'render_custom_link_page');
 }

 function render_custom_link_page() {
    echo 'Custom Link Page';
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed reply! It really helps a lot. Thank you!

Comment: @archangel17 Great.. I'm glad this helped!

Comment: Method 1 worked well for my custom post type. Thx !

Comment: Thank you @SyedFakharAbbas. The first option worked for me as well. I wanted to add my option page tabs as submenu items. The only issue I'm having is adding the current class to the submenu links. Do you know how I can do this?